# How to sudo another user without password

Tags: sudo

Parts of the configuration in my /etc/sudousers

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
web ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
somebody ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

I have two non-super users granted with sudo-without passsword. Each of them can become the root without password, but I try this:

```
web@web01:~$ sudo -u somebody sudo echo "success"
[sudo] password for web:
```

let user `web` to become `somebody` and execute another `sudo` command, the system ask me for password.
How do I configure sudouser to disalbe the password-asked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append the following entry to the end of your sudoers file.

```
somebody ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something along these lines:

```
web@web01:~$ sudo su - somebody
Last login: Wed Mar  1 01:22:27 CST 2017 on pts/1
somebody@web01:~$ sudo whoami
root
somebody@web01:~$ exit
web@web01:~$ #success
```