# Pass password in ssh config

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

Is there any way to pass a password using `.ssh/config`? I'm trying to set up a way to login to a server under a specific user and then switch automatically to root when I connect (need to input password).

For now, I have:

```
Host server
 HostName hostname.server.com
 User not-root
 Port 1234
 RemoteCommand su
```

- I have to use these steps (user -> su)
- I have to use this key (with passphrase)

Comment: use sudo instead.

Comment: I still need to input the user password

Comment: No, you can configure sudo to allow the switch without password.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sudo another user without password](https://serverfault.com/questions/835557/how-to-sudo-another-user-without-password)

Comment: I can't actually change anything on the server so that's not an option for me

Comment: you could try to use "expect" to automate the ssh followed by "su" if it is available for your platform. check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147566/expect-script-for-remote-ssh-login-and-executing-commands

Comment: Uhhh: *"I can't actually change anything on the server so that's not an option for me"*  - but you have the root password, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39347365/specifying-password-in-ssh-config-file

Answer (score 6):

In general most sysadmins would configure things so that their automation does not rely on passwords.

## SSH

For SSH authentication the easiest is to create a key-pair where the private key is not password protected.

If you need a passphrase on the private SSH key, adding that key / passphrase to ssh-agent (or a Mac OSX keychain) is a one-off action after which so you won't  need to be prompted for the passphrase anymore.

If that is not an option, use [`sshpass`](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ssh-automation-sshpass) in your scripts/commands use a password/passphrase from the command line

## On the server

Again the easiest/conventional solution is to prevent having to enter a password.

Your options for that depend on the level of control you have

- set up a NOPASSWD sudo policy (ideally only for the relevant command(s)) which will allow you to execute `sudo some-command --with args` or `sudo -i` for an interactive login session without entering a passphrase.
- set up the root account for direct remote ssh logins (not the best solution, but when you don't allow password auth, only key based auth...)
- depending on the set-up simply add your account to a "sudo" , "wheel" or "admin" group and you get full admin rights

When you really want to submit a password, `expect` is the utility for automating that